# Element X is not allowed in Component tag within .idea XML configuration files

Tags: webstorm, package.json

I always get this error whenever I have a package.json file in my root project folder:

"Element X is not allowed"

This error appears in Component tags within .idea XML configuration files by the code analysis.

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that `.xml` files are vtreated as Vue templates in Vue.js projects; issue is tracked as [WEB-34597](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-34597)